# How to pipe the output of a sed command into a function in unix

Tags: c, csv, unix, sed, pipe

I have this C function that I am using to output any amount of integer that is input.

```
/*
  This program will be called function.c
*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

   int num;

   while(scanf("%d",&num)==1) {
     printf("You entered: %d\n",num);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

In my shell the function works like this as expected with the pipe command

```
$echo "1 7 3 " | ./function
```

Output:

```
You entered: 1
You entered: 7
You entered: 3
```

Now what I'm trying to do is use the *sed* command on a *csv* file and *pipe* the output into my function.

Here is my CSV file

```
$cat file.csv
```

Output:

```
 2,2,3,3,8
```

Using the *sed* command I remove the commas

```
$sed 's/,/ /g' file.csv
```

Output:

```
2 2 3 3 8
```

Now the issue I have is when I try to use the output of the *sed* command to *pipe* the numbers into my function:

```
$sed 's/,/ /g' file.csv | ./function
```

I get no output. I don't know if there is a syntax error, but I believe I should be able to do this with a csv file.

Comment: Did you copy-paste your actual commands? Change `./funtion` to `./function`.

Comment: @Beta yea i did, that was a typing error I made on this post.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on Linux, I get `You entered: 2` and so on

Comment: can't reproduce, even when file.csv ends with `...8<EOF>` (not `...8<newline><EOF>`)

Comment: Piping the output of `sed` is not semantically different from piping the output of `echo`.  It's not clear why you observe the behavior you describe, but the code and shell commands presented do not explain it.  My best guesses would be (1) you're not running the `function` you think you are; (2) the file contents are not what you think they are at the time you perform your test; or (3) some aspect of your execution environment (e.g. quirks of an IDE's output window) is causing the output to be hidden / lost.

Comment: If you're going to use `sed` to replace commas with spaces, use `sed 'y/,/ /'`.  But don't use `sed` for that, use `tr`: `tr , ' '`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I say you have a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in "file.csv".

That will stop `./function` from scanning the first number.

```
$ hexdump -C file.csv
00000000  ef bb bf 32 2c 32 2c 33  2c 33 2c 38 0a           |...2,2,3,3,8.|
0000000d

$ sed 's/,/ /g' file.csv |hexdump -C
00000000  ef bb bf 32 20 32 20 33  20 33 20 38 0a           |...2 2 3 3 8.|
0000000d

$ cat file.csv
2,2,3,3,8

$ cut -b4- file.csv |sed 's/,/ /g' |./function
You entered: 2
You entered: 2
You entered: 3
You entered: 3
You entered: 8

$ sed 's/,/ /g' file.csv |cut -b4- |./function
You entered: 2
You entered: 2
You entered: 3
You entered: 3
You entered: 8
```